# iOS HTML InnerText with Parsing

Tags: javascript, html, ios, parsing

I am using the HTMLNode parser (https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) to parse HTML from a website.

I am able to parse HTML perfectly when there are attributes and tags, but I am having an issue trying to get the innerHTML.

Does someone know how I can get the innerHTML on iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you don't can you javascript syntax by parsing XML or HTML.
I know this library not really good. But i think you can find your desired Element with:

```
-(HTMLNode*)findChildWithAttribute:(NSString*)attribute matchingName:(NSString*)className allowPartial:(BOOL)partial
```

and the child elements or innerHTML with `-(NSArray*)children`

Comment: Just wanted to add that there's also a [`rawContents`](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser/blob/master/HTMLNode.h#L78-L79) property if you want the HTML as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can put that HTML on webview and use "StringByEvaluatingJavaScriprtFromString" Method to get the innerHTMl of the Element, this method will return a string.

Below are some example

**For all element with id**

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"ios-open\").innerHTML"];

**for Body you can use this code**

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];